# Terrarium electric board

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

[hope this isn't off topic for this board]

I'm doing a DIY electric board for my terrarium: in case something goes wrong at least the whole electric circuit won't switch off.

My current setup is a C10 breaker followed by a main on/off switch, and then an on/off switch for every power outlet. All switches have a light to show if it's on or off.

Red is "phase", Black is "phase" returning from switch, Blue neutral and green/yellow is earth. The light for switches have a black cable. (*) These are the French standards, and the board will be plugged in a French power outlet (230V AC, 50 Hz).

**Question:**
I think that a C10 breaker is too much. I'm thinking of putting either a C6 or a C2 breaker.
From where to where do I mesure the current total instensity when all appliances are on?

[image]

(*) Sorry for my lack of lingo, but google translate didn't help much.

Comment: You might want to mention where you are - electrical standards and practices vary quite a bit world wide, so knowledge of the locality may be necessary.

Comment: @MichaelKohne BlakBat's profile says *France*, but the work could be anywhere.

Comment: You should be able to estimate the load (which is the way overcurrent protection is usually selected), using the labeling on the devices you'll be connecting.  Current (I) = wattage (power)(p) / voltage (V), though some devices might have current ratings listed directly. This will give you the current for each device. Since it looks to be a parallel circuit, total current (It) = I1 + I2 + I3...

Comment: @MichaelKohne: good remark. bib: good deduction.
I'll edit the question to specify that this is done for a french circuit board.

Comment: @tester101: I have a wattmeter that I just plugged in before the main switch. It currently reads 70W. So 70 / 230 (estimate, not measured) = 0,30A.

That means that a C2 breaker should be more than sufficient if my calculations are correct? right?

Comment: There's really no reason to put in a smaller breaker than the maximum of the weakest component of your board can handle, but if it makes you feel better then go ahead and use a C2.

Comment: @BlakBat I think you're over thinking this a bit.  The circuit breaker is there to protect the wire in the circuit. As long as the breaker is sized properly for that, there shouldn't be a problem.  In the US for example. If you were using 14 AWG wire, it's rated for 15 amperes. So you'd use a 15 ampere breaker. Size your wires to the load, size your breaker to the wires.